# How to get markdown working in Assemble?

Tags: assemble

I'm setting up assemble in grunt. It's a little difficult because the devs seem to have changed a lot about the installation process, but there's no updated documentation.

Does anyone know how to set up markdown processing?

I've tried a few things - I found a post that mentioned installing `handlebars-helper-md` so I tried that.

My assemble task looks like this:

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        layout: 'page.hbs',
        layoutdir: './src/content/layouts',
        partials: ['./src/content/partials/**/*.hbs', './src/content/partials/**/*.md'],
        assets: 'assets',
        helpers: ['handlebars-helper-md'],
        data: ['package.json', './src/content/data/*.json'],
        marked: {
            breaks: false,
            gfm: true,
            langPrefix: 'language-',
            pedantic: false,
            sanitize: false,
            silent: false,
            smartLists: false,
            smartypants: false,
            tables: true
        }
    },
    project: {
        files: [{
            cwd: './src/content/pages',
            dest: './dist/www',
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/*.hbs']
        }]
    }
},
```

then I've put markdown files into these places (none of which work):

1. `./src/content/markdown/privacy.md`
2. `./src/content/partials/privacy.md`
3. Directly in the template

my template is located in `./src/content/pages/content/privacy-policy.hbs` and looks like this:

```
title: Privacy
description: The privacy policy
tags:
- content
- legal
text: ./markdown/privacy.md
---
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <p>This is a quick test for the privacy policy content</p>

        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            Test 1:
            {{md './markdown/privacy.md'}}

            relative to the hbs file perhaps?
            {{md '../../markdown/privacy.md'}}

        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            Test 2:
            {{>privacy}}

        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            Test3:

            {{md text}}

        </div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black">
            Test4:
            {{#markdown}}
                ## Hello World
            {{/markdown}}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



            smartLists: false,
            smartypants: false,
            tables: true
        }
    },
    project: {
        files: [{
            cwd: './src/content/pages',
            dest: './dist/www',
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/*.hbs']
        }]
    }
},
```

Then, basically two methods kind of work - but the markdown isn't processed. This is a picture of the output:

[image]

Comment: The indentation in Test4 could be causing the markdown to render as a code block. Try moving `## Hello World` all the way to the left. For the `{{md}}` helper try using the link relative to the `process.cwd()`, so something like `{{md './src/content/markdown/privacy.md'}}`

Comment: Thanks that fixed test 4, so markdown is working. But test 1 I couldn't get -  I set it relative to the explicit cwd - so "../markdown/privacy.md", even if it's relative to the layouts directory in the options, it should still be correct. But still not resolving. is there any way to print the cwd into the page?

Comment: https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-md#usage-examples have you tried using just `{{md 'privacy'}}`?

Comment: I tried it with:  ` {{md '../markdown/privacy'}}`, `{{md './markdown/privacy'}}`,` {{md 'privacy'}}` and a few others but still nothing working...

Comment: Is there any way to view more logs on what the helpers are doing? I dug into some of the helper code and it seems to log to the js console. Probably works if the template's used in a browser, but is there any way to see that output from the assemble process?

Comment: not that it helps much - but I'm not sure if this issue is relevant - does this helper even support paths? - https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-md/issues/1

Comment: ah bravo! I got it - so that seems to be the answer - it only works with partials, and I was missing this in the configuration (note including *.md in the files).  project: {
                files: [{
                    cwd: './src/content/pages',
                    dest: './dist/www',
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['**/*.{hbs,md}']
                }]
            }  -- feel free to post the answer and I'll give you the points for helping out Cheers.

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest making sure the markdown was registered as partials, but I misread the config posted above and thought it already was. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: it was definitely already declared in the partials, but it needed to be in the "files" section of the project task.

Comment: that's weird I just took it out of the files section to double check, and it's still working. I'm sure that didn't work before with {{md 'privacy'}} ... weird, must be I was doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handlebars-helper-markdown` is still designed to work with `grunt-assemble` and it looks for partials that have been registered with the `partials` option in the task configuration.

You just need to add `./src/content/markdown/*.md` to your `partials` array, then use `{{md "privacy"}}` for the helper to find the `privacy.md` file to render.

I notice you have `privacy.md` in 2 places. In `grunt-assemble` this will result in only the last `privacy.md` partial being loaded. FYI in case you run into that issue. We'll be refactoring the `grunt-assemble` internals soon to match up to functionality in `assemble@0.7.0` to handle situations like this.